# CSS selector: only select child if there is more than one child

Tags: css

it is actually quite simple:

If I have several children, I want `.child` to have `margin-bottom: 10px;`
if there is only one child, I don't want to have that margin

obviously:
Just adding another class to the container is not an option. **CSS solution only**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>
```

so first container's child should have *no margin*. The other examples should have a margin between each child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the **[`:first-of-type`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/)** pseudo-class in conjunction with the **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** negation pseudo-class, and set `margin-top` instead. This will only give the `margin-top` to child elements which have a preceding element, thus giving the separation effect you're looking for:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll give it to you as I didn't know that selector, the other answer is just as good

Answer (score 2):

You can add a margin to each element after a previous one, so we only have `margin-top` if there is an element before.

```css
.container {
 border:2px solid;
 margin:20px;
}
.child {
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
.child + .child {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Or remove the `margin-bottom` from the last element so when having only one element it will also be the last element:

```css
.container {
 border:2px solid;
 margin:20px;
}
.child {
  height:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:red;
}
.child:last-child {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
/* OR
.child:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
  <div class="child">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great answer, I accepted the other one though as I didnt know the selector he used. As well: probably `.child ~ .child` is better than `.child + .child` if there is different content in the container as well. As `+` will only add the margin if a .child is followed by a. child, and not say, .child .somethingelse .child

Comment: @Toskan no I meant exactly + :) because each child will add a margin to only next one ..if I use ~ it means that each one will add margin to all the next  ... for `~` it would be like this `:first-child ~ *` : in this case only the first child will add margin to all the others

Comment: you mean `:first-child ~ .child` or maybe I dont get it? `*` would add to other elements, even non `.child`

Comment: @Toskan since all your elements are `.child` then both are the same, we are targetting all the child elements

Comment: yes you are right. I am just saying, "what if there were other elements as well" then `+` wouldn't work any longer. I am just trying to come up with scenarios where something else might be better. But you are very correct: for the exact example, `+` is just perfect